# Selectively remove command history of Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

I would like to selectively remove some of the history in Windows Terminal. History refers to the past commands typed into the Windows Terminal.

How can this be done?

I'm using Windows 10, Windows Terminal 1.8.1521.

Comment: As @NotTheDr01ds mentions, adding information about which shell (Powershell, bash, etc.) will help narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: Remember to close this out via an accept (or another answer) if it is resolved for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The command history in Windows Terminal is managed by whatever shell application you are using in it.

You don't mention which shell you are using, but here are a few possibilities:

- If you are using WSL with the `bash` shell, then `history -c` clears the history for the current shell instance.  Deleting the file `~/.bash_history` will clear the *save* history from previous sessions.  You can selectively remove an entry from the current session using `history -d <offset>` (use `history` by itself to see the offset).
- If you are using WSL with the `fish` shell, then `history clear` both clears the current shell history *and* deletes past history.  `history delete ...` can be used to remove specific entries.  See `man history` under `fish` for more info.
- If you are using WSL with `zsh`, it seems to be a little more complicated -- I'll just provide a [link to a separate answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544815/432493) on that.
- If you are using PowerShell, then `Clear-History` may clear it for a particular session.  But if you are using the `psreadline` module (which is a default on most recent PowerShell versions, you may need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> instead.  To clear the permanent history file, you'll need to find it with `Get-PSReadlineOption | select -expand historysavepath` and then delete that file.
- If you are using the `CMD` shell (the "old" Windows/DOS compatible shell), then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> will clear the whole history. CMD does not permanently store a history file, so there's probably no need to delete one item.

  However, if you would like to clean up individual entries anyway, you can open the history popup with <kbd>F7</kbd>, select an item using <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>, and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove it.

Note that this all refers to the *command history*.  There is also the concept of the scrollback buffer in Windows Terminal.  In PowerShell and most WSL/Linux shells, the `clear` command will clear that.